# oracle insert 1 row multiple columns into multiple rows one column

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a table t1 that contains the following : (millions of rows)

```
ID    ID_1    ID_2   ID_3   ID_4
---------------------------------
1      10      11     12     13
2      14      15     16     17
3      18      19     20     21
```

I need to insert these data in another table t2 as following:

```
ID     ID_X
------------
1       10
1       11
1       12
1       13
2       14
2       15
2       16
2       17
3       18
3       19
3       20
3       21
```

I already did what I need using LOOPs and cursors , but I need to do it with a single insert for better performance.

any ideas ?

**EDIT:**

I achieved what I needed using UNPIVOT thanks to replies.

Now I need to go further by adding an increment column to t2 table as follows:

```
ID     ID_X     ID_Y
----------------------
1       10       0
1       11      200
1       12      400
1       13      600
2       14       0
2       15      200
2       16      400
2       17      600
3       18       0
3       19      200
3       20      400
3       21      600
```

Comment: What you're after is [UNPIVOT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1), assuming you're on 11g or higher

Comment: Please don't edit extra bits onto the question once they've been answered. Instead, you should ask a new question to cover the new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT`.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ID, ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, ID_4 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 10, 11, 12, 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 14, 15, 16, 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 18, 19, 20, 21 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t2 ( ID NUMBER, ID_X NUMBER );
```

**Insert Statement**:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (id, id_x )
  SELECT id, value
  FROM   t1
  UNPIVOT ( value FOR name IN ( ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, ID_4 ) );
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

```
ID | ID_X
-: | ---:
 1 |   10
 1 |   11
 1 |   12
 1 |   13
 2 |   14
 2 |   15
 2 |   16
 2 |   17
 3 |   18
 3 |   19
 3 |   20
 3 |   21
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8f1a335af4d79b55bb5eec20eb3d4e05)*

Comment: thanks! that what I needed! 
can you please check the edit on my post as I need to add new column to my table

Comment: @ghostman `200*ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY name ) AS id_y`

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION` this can be achievable. The following query will work :

```
INSERT INTO Newtable (ID, ID_X) 
SELECT ID, ID_X FROM (
    SELECT ID, ID_1 AS ID_X FROM TableName UNION
    SELECT ID, ID_2 AS ID_X FROM TableName UNION
    SELECT ID, ID_3 AS ID_X FROM TableName UNION  
    SELECT ID, ID_4 AS ID_X FROM TableName
) A
ORDER BY ID, ID_X
```

Comment: Since the post is about Oracle, but working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b110aac40cc1cacf17440c81e5ddd61) with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

`select ID, ID_X from test
unpivot(ID_X for value in (ID_1 as 'A', ID_2 as 'B',ID_3 as 'C',ID_4 as 'D'));`